How to create multiple inherited tree, form views for the same model
I need to customize the account.move form view in Odoo to meet different requirements based on the type of view being accessed. Since account.move is used for various purposes like vendor bills, customer invoices, and journal entries, I want to create separate views for each of these use cases.
Each custom view should inherit the original account.move form view and apply specific changes. For example:

A separate view for vendor bills.
A separate view for customer invoices.
A separate view for journal entries.

When accessing a specific type of view (eg, vendor bill or customer invoice), the corresponding view should be displayed automatically based on the type of document being viewed. How can I implement this while ensuring that all these views inherit the original account move form view. I am using odoo version 17.

Define your action like below
      <field name="name">Fee Items</field>
      <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
      <field name="res_model">product.product</field>
      <field name="binding_view_types">form</field>
      <field name="view_mode">kanban,tree,form</field>
      <field name="domain">[('is_fee_product', '=', True)]</field>
      <field name="context">
        {'default_is_fee_product':True,'default_detailed_type':'service','default_sale_ok':True}</field>
    </record>

Then define a tree view
<record id="fee_product_view_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
      <field name="name">fee.product.view.tree</field>
      <field name="model">product.product</field>
      <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <tree string="Fee Items">
          <field name="name" />
          <field name="is_section_entry" widget="boolean_toggle" />
          <field name="class_ids" widget="many2many_tags" />
          <field name="term_ids" widget="many2many_tags" />
          <field name="categ_id" />
          <field name="lst_price" widget="monetary" />
        </tree>
      </field>
    </record>

Then define this action view type that binds this view to your custom tree view. you can create extra view types like below for your custom form and search view.
  <record model="ir.actions.act_window.view" id="act_open_fee_item_tree">
      <field name="act_window_id" ref="fees_action" />
      <field name="sequence" eval="10" />
      <field name="view_mode">tree</field>
      <field name="view_id" ref="fee_product_view_tree" />
    </record>

